# Is there a way to have autocompletion for Backbone.js in Notepad++?

Tags: backbone.js, autocomplete, notepad++

As the title says. I can't find a plugin or something that will help me code in backbone.

Comment: I think. you can use [Brackets](http://brackets.io)

Comment: It looks like a really nice editor, I might check it out, but I would like to have autocompletion in notepad++ right now :/.

Comment: There are [some packages](https://github.com/search?q=sublime+backbone&nwo=tomasztunik%2FSublime-Text-2-Backbone.js-package&search_target=global&ref=cmdform) for sumblime, you may want to try porting them to notepad++

Comment: sorry. I don't know. I use brackets all day. So i don't know about it. Others may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't used this package but it seems to fit your needs.

https://github.com/ryansukale/bootcamp

**Bundled Frameworks.**

- jQuery
- jQueryUI
- requirejs
- Twitter bootstrap.
- underscorejs
- backbonejs
- HTML 5 Modernizer